# Creating a Skeleton/Template SUSE or SLES Linux Server

Tags: linux, opensuse, sles, zypper

**Scenario:**  I have a "template" server with all the services and packages installed which will be replicated on many new servers.

Each newly replicated server will be stood up by installing a specific version of SLES (15 SP4 in this case), then registered and configured for local network.

My plan is to tar up /home, /root, & /usr from my template server and cherry pick config files out of /etc, then extract the tarball on the new server.

My goal is to transfer the list of installed apps and startup services originally managed using YaST from my template server to the new replicated servers.

I suppose the real question I am trying to ask is where or how does SLES/SUSE store installed services and package manager information?  Is there a single location or directory I can migrate or is this a much more complicated question?

Comment: I would not recommend this way. if you really want to do so I would suggest that you take a look at lxc

Comment: While a good suggestion, these new replicated servers will all end up on a VMWare stack of their own all over the country.  I'm trying to get away from shipping out huge VMDK files for this process as it's super easy to install the OS on a fresh VM then send something much smaller that can be sent over the internet.

Comment: the only less configuration would be to use docker, that would be the smallest deployment

Comment: Or you use [autoyast](https://documentation.suse.com/sles/15-SP4/html/SLES-all/book-autoyast.html) to clone your template machine, then use that autoyast template to install all other machines.

Comment: You might give the SUSE Manager a try, it will provide solutions to all your problems. As far as I know, when you have at least 10 SLES subscriptions, SUSE Manager can be subscripted free of charge. Ask your SUSE dealer. PS SUSE Manager is a very complex tool and should always be used in a predefined way, always use the latest version